# How to remove rows from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I'm loading CSV Files into a IEnumerable.

```
  string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(@"read\", "*.csv");
  for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Length; i++)
  { 
       string file = @"read\" + Path.GetFileName(fileNames[i]);
       var lines   = from rawLine in File.ReadLines(file, Encoding.Default)
                     where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawLine) 
                     select rawLine;
  }
```

After that I work with the Data but now there are couple of Files that are pretty much empty and only have ";;;;;;" (the amount varies) written in there.

How can I delete those rows before working with them and without changing anything in the csv files?

Comment: You want to delete them from the file? Or exclude them from the enumerable? If the latter - see what you did with the `where` - that is how you how include or exclude them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the amount of `;` characters per line is variable, this is what your "where" condition should look like:

```
where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawLine) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawLine.Trim(';'))
```

`rawLine.Trim(';')` will return a copy of the string with all `;` characters removed. If this new string is empty, it means this line can be ignored, since it only contained `;` characters.

Comment: The `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawLine)` is logically redundant.

Comment: I disagree. While a `rawLine != null` might have been enough as well (to avoid NullReferenceException when calling `rawLine.Trim(';')`, I don't think it is bad practice to check whether a string is null OR empty before doing any additional processing or calculations.

Comment: @Kwinten: i'd prefer `rawLine.Trim(';').Any()` though. Also the line is never `null` so even the first `IsNullOrEmpty`-call is only used to check if `rawLine.Length > 0`

Comment: @TimSchmelter good point on `rawLine` never being null in the first place. Of course this can change depending on the source of the data provider. Your first suggestion won't compile, `string.Any()` is not defined in any standard library.

Comment: @Kwinten: a `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, you can use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx) if you add `using System.Linq`. Of course you could also use `rawLine.Trim(';').Length > 0`

Comment: @TimSchmelter you are right, `string` does implement this interface for some versions of .NET. Strangely enough, for Windows Store apps, `string` only implements `IEnumerable`. Either way, `string.IsNullOrEmpty` does not add any overhead and is more legible than `string.Any` in my opinion.

Comment: What ever might be better, im very thankfull that worked like a charm! Thank to all of you!

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove anything from an `IEnumerable`(like from a `List<T>`), buty ou can add a filter:

```
lines = lines.Where(l => !l.Trim().All(c => c == ';'));
```

This won't delete anything, but you won't process these lines anymore.

Comment: Proably "better" to avoid Trim and use `c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || c == ';'` "Better" in the sense of: doesn't matter unless it is used alot ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo: why is that better? `String.Strim` removes only leading and trailing spaces, your approach also acccepts spaces between the semicolons. Thats a different logic. OP only mentioned `";;;;;;"`(without spaces).

Comment: Oh, yes. You are right. Didn't notice that. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove rows from an enumerable - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx.

Instead try creating a new array with the filtered data or filter it on the `where` clause that you presented like:

```
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(@"read\", "*.csv");
         for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Length; i++)
            { string file = @"read\" + Path.GetFileName(fileNames[i]);
var lines = from rawLine in File.ReadLines(file, Encoding.Default) where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawLine) && rawLine != ";;;;;;" select rawLine;}
```

Comment: For this not to be a comment-like answer I'd recommed you to post the fix.

Comment: The OP appears to me to say that the number of semi-colons is variable, so the where could be `(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawLine) && !Regex.IsMatch(rawLine, "^;+$"))` to take that into account.

Comment: In that case it's possible to use the linq function All (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) on the text, like it's showed in another reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51173946/9989577

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solution.

1. Convert enumerable to List, then delete from List. This is bit expensive.
2. Create one function. // You can apply multiple filter in case required.

   ```
   public IEnumrable<string> GetData(ref IEnumrable<string> data)
   {
         return data.Where(c=> !String.Equals(c,"<<data that you want to filter>>");  
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As another option to read CSV file is to make use of [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) class. It has `CommentTokens` and `Delimiters` which may help you on this.

Specifying `;` as a `CommentTokens` may help you.

[Tutorial](https://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2010/05/Do-you-know-the-TextFieldParser.aspx)